# ios10 unable to download app

Tags: ios10, enterprise, ad-hoc-distribution, iphone-developer-program, in-house-distribution

I have an Apple Enterprise In-House application that I am unable to install.  I've tried 3 different iOS10 phones and an iPad - I get the same error - Unable to Download App "Application Name" could not be installed at this time.

I've checked the log while the phone is installing the application.  I don't get any errors regarding invalid certificates, etc - it all looks good to me also.

The app just seems to refuse to install and the logs don't help.

I've posted the log here http://www.zackburns.com/files/public/tmp/ios10noinstall.txt

I've also verified the server is doing TLS 1.2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For others that stumble upon this...

The offending line was.....

installd(MobileSystemServices)[438] : 0x16e03b000 -[MIInstallableBundle performVerificationWithError:]: 785: Failed to unhide archs in executable file:///private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.MY8YZE/extracted/Payload/EmployeeTimes.app/com.zzzzzzzzz.employeetimes

I recompiled the Application for 32-bit vs 64-bit (which to me is odd) because it's an iPhone 6 which is supposed to be 64-bit.

Comment: And it may be due to how the compiler is handling this.  You may have to enable both arm7 and arm64 compiling.